# What is the proper way to pass the connection to the DB in a Servicestack message based design

Tags: asp.net, servicestack, asp.net-core-2.1

I have problems deciding on how the OrmLiteConnectionFactory should be passed to the different classes. Should it be done by injecting the container into the constructors? It is a message based design if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you'd just want to pass a "reference" to what connection you'd want your Service to be executed with.

ServiceStack's [Multitenancy docs](http://docs.servicestack.net/multitenancy) shows different approaches of specifying the DB connection to use per Request DTO message, including using a [custom filter](http://docs.servicestack.net/multitenancy#changedb-request-filter), or utilizing the built-in `[ConnectionInfo]` or `[NamedConnection]` attributes.

Or if you prefer you can resolve which DB connection you want to use with your Services logic by resolving it from a [IDbConnectionFactory dependency](http://docs.servicestack.net/multitenancy#resolving-named-connections-in-services).

Comment: Thanks for the help!